# psql: fatal: database "my_db" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

`psql -d my_db -U my_user -h my.com`

same command works fine from other machines, but not from this particular machine.

I'm scratching my heads over many hours now and failed to google it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you ping `my.com`? What does it give you when you do an `nslookup` on it from the different machines? Can you telnet to its psql port? What's the actual error you see? Are you wearing clean underwear in case you get hit by a bus? Any number of things could be causing this issue although, admittedly, the channeling of my long-dead mother is an unlikely one :-)

Comment: the error is same as the title of this question, yes I can ping, telnet to psql port of `my.com` my eyeglasses are always dirty..

Comment: `psql -L -U my_user -h my.com postgres` should list the available databases

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the port via `-p <port>`. It may be that the *Postgres* binaries on this particular box were compiled with a different default port, or have the `PGPORT` [environment variable](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) set whereas the other boxes do not.

The default port is usually `5432`, although that can be compiled in differently or set in the server config differently.

Since it says that the DB does not exist, as opposed to that it can't connect, I suspect that it's not a core networking issue (unless `my.com` happened to be rerouted via `/etc/hosts` to some other box that happened to also have a *Postgres* instance on it with the same password and access permissions, but that seems somewhat unlikely, unless perhaps it was redirected to `localhost` for testing, which could be the case, although that seems less likely).